# Where can I define where I want the image (with absolute positioning) to placed upon refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here in my code there is a picture of Mario, however he is always at the top of the screen and I can't find out which parameters to edit to change his immediate positioning upon refreshing the page. In other words which part of my code (I'm guessing it's in the html absolute positioning tag of the Mario image) do I change to be able to make Mario appear at the bottom of the screen.

```js
// TIMER
window.onload = function () {
//this is where you can modifies the time amount.
    var minutes= 29 ,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(minutes, display);
};


function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
            window.alert("GAME OVER ( F5 TO PLAY AGAIN! )");
            
        }
    }, 1000);
}



// MOVEMENT

function leftArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("Mario");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function rightArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("Mario");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

            }

            function upArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("Mario");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function downArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("Mario");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
            }

            function moveSelection(evt) {
                switch (evt.keyCode) {
                    case 37:
                    leftArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 39:
                    rightArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 38:
                    upArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 40:
                    downArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    }
                };

        function docReady()
        {
          
          window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
        }
```

```css
html {
  background-image:url("BACKGROUND.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1920px 1080px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Title {
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #52db3d;
  display:inline;
}
.Titlev2 {
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000000;
  display:inline;
}
.Titlev3 {
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #e60000;
  display:inline;
}

#Luigi {
  height:450px;
  width:960px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}

#Timer {
  font-family:Bebas Neue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jeu</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CSS.css">
<script src="JS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="">
  <h1 class="Title">Luigi  </h1>
   <h1 class="Titlev2">V.S  </h1>
    <h1 class="Titlev3">Mario</h1>
     <img id="Mario" src="MarioSprite.png" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;" height="450" width="960">
     <img id="Luigi" src="LuigiSprite.png">
     <div id="Timer"><h1><span id="time">00:30</span></h1></div>
     <audio autoplay src="Soundtrack.mp3"></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mario needs to learn from Luigi. His inline style is what's causing his problems.  Inline styles are troublesome as they are difficult to override in CSS without starting to pepper your code with !important rules.  I'd remove that inline style and style it how you want in the CSS, like Luigi.

Comment: Haha, I appreciate the positive attitude towards a noob. When you say the inline style, you're suggesting that I remove the height, width and position from the html and put it into the CSS as #Mario? After that, how would I go about to change his vertical positioning?

Comment: Yep. Avoid putting styles in your HTML markup. It's a bad practice. Put it in your CSS, then you would just change the 'top' style to position it lower or higher.  Can be a percent, a pixel value, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Comment: I have moved the height width and position under Mario in CSS, however now he is capable of moving and changing the top tag doesen't do anything.